# Is there a way to create a plan branch for all pull requests AND a custom set of branches in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

When creating a plan branch, is there a way to configure Bamboo to make new branch when a pull request is created and in addition, for a set of branches that match a custom regex?

[image]

So it would be a combination of 2nd and 4th option

Comment: It seems as there isn't a native way of doing it. There is a ticket open for this [feature with Bamboo](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-19825?_ga=2.26361405.1013094797.1537804201-817953018.1508336944). Please go vote on prioritizing this if you need this feature!

Comment: This sucks, seems like it's a popular use case (e.g. run different plan when merging to develop, master etc.)